# how to handle quotes on using javascript eval

Tags: javascript, string, escaping, quotes

```
var userString = `var a='sister\'s'`
eval(userString) //error
```

I will get the user string and do eval, it throws parse error since the string is escaped.
How to eval it properly , i saw we can ,make some regex handling and replace quotes but i am not sure it will work efficiently since the user's javascript content can be any javascript content. Is there any universal method?

Comment: You need to escape the backslash so it will be put into it literally.

Comment: Did you try `console.log(userString)` to see what it was?

Comment: This is only an issue if you're writing `userString` literally in the program. If you get it from the user, you don't have to do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can make use of [string.raw](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw) api

```
var userString = String.raw`var a='sister\'s'`;
eval(userString) //no error and variable 'a' will have the expected value.
```

Answer (score -1):

To put a literal backslash into `userString` you have to double it.

```js
var userString = `var a='sister\\'s'; console.log(a);`
console.log(userString);
eval(userString) //error
```

Comment: dude , i know i have to to use double slash. since its user string i need to do replace() ryt. im asking tat code Like userString.replaceAll("\\","\\\\")

Comment: You don't need to do anything with user input. This is only needed for string literals.

Comment: yes dude, the user will pass me a valid string which he was written in his file as

```var a = 'sister\'s';  console.log(a);```

Acoording to the user this is a valid string, when i try to do eval , the single slash is escaped and throws error. i am asking how to prevent it. i can't change the actual content to ```var a='sister\\'s'; console.log(a);``` as u said, rather what i can do is get the string and do ```string.replaceAll("\\","\\\\")``` but this also fails as slash is escaing before replaceall, is there anything to achieve this?

Comment: If they're writing a string literal in their file, THEY have to escape the backslash. This can't be optional, because then you'll never know which backslashes and quotes that you receive need to be escaped.

Comment: According to the user, in his some.js file , we would have written 
``` var a = 'sister's'; console.log(a) ; ```
according to user it is the correct and valid code. i cant tell him backslash every slash. i am the one reading that file and processing it.

Comment: The problem is that incorrectly escaped code is ambiguous. Suppose he does write double backslash -- is he escaping the backslash, or writing two unescaped backslashes that your code needs to double?

Comment: he does write double backslash -- is he escaping the backslash ? - yes